# How to change the Access token lifetime in OpenAM 12

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token, openam, forgerock

How can I change the access token lifetime from default 60s in OpenAM 12? I couldn’t figure out the corresponding configurations. Appreciate if someone could help me to do the necessary changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can see it in OAuth2 Provider configuration ([Global configuration](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/12/reference/#oauth2-provider-configuration)).

> **Access Token Lifetime**
>
> Lifetime of OAuth 2.0 access token in seconds.
>
> ssoadm attribute: forgerock-oauth2-provider-access-token-lifetime

This can be set for each OAuth 2.0 client since 13.5.

See also: [OpenAM 13.5 Reference](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/admin-guide/#configure-oauth2-client)